# Equation $(p-1)! + 1 = p^n$ for some $p > 5$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

*Wilson's Theorem* states that a natural number $p > 1$ is a prime if and only if $(p-1)!$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $p$. A natural question to ask is: For which $p$ is $(p-1)!$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $p^2$? About these numbers, called *Wilson primes*, not much is known: as far as I know, the only known Wilson primes are $5$, $13$ and $563$ and it is conjectured that there are infinitely many Wilson primes.

Here, I would like to focus on the following more special question.

> Are there some prime $p>5$ and some integer $n > 1$ such that $(p-1)! + 1 = p^n$?

**Remarks:**

- By Wilson's Theorem, it is necessary that $p$ is a prime.
- For $p = 5$, the assertion is satisfied with $n = 2$.
- For $n = 1$, one can easily solve the equation and see that $p=2$ and $p=3$ are the only possible numbers in this case.

**What I've tried:**  First of all, I suspect that the equation does not have a solution in $p > 5$, $n > 1$, but I will suppose that the equation holds to get some necessary conditions on $p$ and $n$, and maybe a contradiction in the end.

- The equation in the question is equivalent to $(p-2)! = 1+...+p^{n-1}$. As the left hand side is divisible by $5$, the right hand side is also. By the same token, the left hand side is even, so the right hand side is also even. Whence, as $p$ is odd, $n$ has to be even.
- The statement does not really depend on $p$ being a prime. By Wilson's Theorem one just knows that $p$ being a prime is necessary, but maybe one does not really need it and can do some kind of induction on $p$ to see that the equation cannot be solved. However, I was not able to do this.
- As $p^p \geq p! \geq (p-1)! + 1 = p^n$, we see that $p \geq n$.
- To show that the equation does not have any solution, it suffices to show that for a fixed $p$ and an arbitrary positive $n > 1$, either

(i) $(p-1)! + 1 < p^n$, or

(ii) $(p-1)! + 1 > p^n$.

I suspect that (i) holds if $n > \frac{p}2$ and that (ii) holds if $n \leq \frac{p-1}2$. If this is true, it would suffice to prove the two statements

(i') $(p-1)! + 1 < p^{(p+1)/2}$, and

(ii') $(p-1)! + 1 > p^{(p-1)/2}$

instead.

- Look at it analytically: The equation becomes $\Gamma(x) + 1 = x^n$. The plots suggest that the equation does not have any solution for $x > 5$ as the left hand side increases much faster than the right hand side. One could try to do some kind of approach with derivatives, but the Gamma-Function is the thing that disturbs me here.

I would be thankful for any approach regarding this problem, thank you!